# XML parsing and storing it in bean while validating against xsd with valid error

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd

Is there any best way to parse xml file and store it in beans while validate it against xsd?

I have a scenario like this.

> I have to parse xml file and store the data in java/spring(preferable) beans,which I want to use in my junit class.

What I thought of doing is that I want to restrict the user to write the xml of specific format.So I want to validate the xml file against xsd.
Is there any best API which does this?

> xml file is a simple file with nested tags and not too big.

Comment: Have you looked into [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_1-Introduction.html#Introduction). Or [Castor](http://castor.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use of JAXB parsing is very good, I think it will really be easy.
You can do something like this::

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("XML_Parent_Element");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                bean.setAttribute(eElement.getElementsByTagName("attribute_name_string")
                        .item(temp).getAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can map the Elements to javabeans?
Also can I validate the xml against schema?

Comment: what exactly do you mean when you say map to java Beans?
and what schema?
provide some code examples...

Comment: What I mean is , while parsing xml can I store the values I extracted from xml into java beans without setting each property induvidually. I don't know whether there is any framework which helps in this mapping with annotations or any other way.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html), however I have never used this, so I am not sure how this works.